# Is that option correct?

Tags: passive-voice

Is the option number 4 correct?

> _________________ to resign from the government.

1. It declared
2. He declare
3. It was declared
4. He has been declared

Comment: None of the answers is idiomatic English.

Comment: @StoneyB: when l first saw the question, l felt that there is something wrong. I thought that option D is the nearest answer. Now you see that none of the opions is very common in English. Would you mind suggesting an appropriate option?

Comment: If we have to use the word *declare*, in a way that fits in the blank, I would write "He declared his intention" or "He declared that he wanted" or maybe "It was declared that he is".  In English, you can't just "declare to *verb*" which makes me think that whoever wrote this question did not speak English very well.

Comment: @stangdon: all your options fit well. By the way, the person who wrote this question is a non-native teacher of English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any common examples that use the form "declare to [verb]" and using that form would sound odd.

This makes sense when you consider that "to declare" means to "to make clearly known or announce officially." *(Collins)*

You can either use it with an object, you can "declare *that* [something]" is the case, or occasionally you can use it intransitively (without an object). The following combinations, for example, would all be commonplace and understood:

> He declared **his resignation** from the government
>
> He has declared **his intention** to resign from the government
>
> It was declared **that** he will resign from the government

Comment: Your suggested options, as well as Stangdon's, are really excellent. I wish I could vote for your answer.

Comment: @MidoMido I only see one answer, which you can accept if you'd like :)

Comment: l guess you will recommend the last sentence, right?

Comment: I would recommend any of the three sentences depending on context. Is he resigning now? Is it even him discussing the resignation?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no context.

Comment: @MidoMido Not in your original question, no. But then none of the answers there are correct either. The correct answer from the above depends on the things mentioned above.